# How do I have multiple wildcards?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wildcard

I am using wxpython and Python v2.7 to make a text editor. Here is my save dialog:

```
dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, 'Save File', self.dirname, 'Untitled', 'All files (*.*)|*.*', wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
```

For the wildcard parameter I have `'All files (*.*)|*.*'`

I need to also have `'Text Document (*.txt)|*.txt'`

How can I have multiple wildcards here, without creating a variable to store them?

Thanks,

xPotatoes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can just do:

```
dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, 'Save File', self.dirname, 'Untitled', 'All files (*.*)|*.*|Text Document (*.txt)|*.txt', wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
```

Just use `|` as a separator and add append pairs of descriptions and wildcard expressions.